# How can I remove the window shadow in Mountain Lion?

Tags: ui

There's an application called ShadowKiller that seems popular and supposedly works for Lion, but it just seems to die as soon as I try to start it on Mountain Lion.

I'd like to get around of the shadows surrounding a window.

Comment: This thread should be extended to OSX Yosetime too, I think.

Answer (score 9):

This one works well for me: [toggle-osx-shadows](https://github.com/puffnfresh/toggle-osx-shadows).

It is easy to compile and use, and there are only 17 lines of code.

Comment: If you don't have XCode, and don't mind downloading from people's Dropbox's, here's the util, which I just compiled on my Mac ;-) I didn't do anything to it, and it worked great for me... But if you're not adventurous, download it from the git repo above and build it yourself!

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/274922/toggle-osx-shadows

You'll have to `chmod 700 toggle-osx-shadows` to make it executable, of course!

Comment: Tested ok on Yosemite : Using brew : brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/puffnfresh/toggle-osx-shadows/master/homebrew/toggle-osx-shadows.rb

Answer (score 1):

[ShadowKiller](http://unsanity.com/haxies/shadowkiller) still works for me on 10.8, but it's supposed to quit silently after it's opened. You can run it at login by adding it to login items.

[Nocturne](http://code.google.com/p/blacktree-nocturne/) also has an option to disable the shadows.

Related questions at Super User:

- [Disable drop shadows around windows or the menu bar on OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/256707/disable-drop-shadows-around-windows-or-the-menu-bar-on-os-x?lq=1)
- [How do I decrease the window shadow in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/126374/how-do-i-decrease-the-window-shadow-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: Ah I see. I tried Nocturne but it seems like the disable shadows option doesn't do anything either.

Comment: It's only available when the night mode is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time on this issue, and even got to the point that I wrote a little program to fix it.  Then I discovered something much simpler:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSUseLeopardWindowValues NO
defaults write com.apple.Safari NSUseLeopardWindowValues YES
```

The second one is necessary because Safari doesn't seem to like the shadows (you get a "Invalid unbuffered shadow parameters." comment in syslog).

Comment: I ran those commands in a terminal window. Nothing happened. Where are they supposed to be modified?. Sorry newbie to Mac.

Comment: so_mv: log out & in; the only thing I notice these commands changing is removing shading on the window title bar... shadows are still cast onto underlying windows

Answer (score 1):

The program I use to do this on OS X 10.8.4 is ShadowSweeper.

http://download.cnet.com/ShadowSweeper/3000-2072_4-75966596.html

This one looks like it might also work but I haven't tried it myself.

https://github.com/puffnfresh/toggle-osx-shadows

Comment: Thanks for the answers on this. Be sure to read the promotion section of [help] if you recommend the same software several times.