# Mountain Lion - scale down the window shadows

Tags: macos

it is just me or did apple increased the size of the window shadows in mountain lion way to much?
This is annoying when you've 2 windows side by side - is there any way to turn them off / to scale them down?

Comment: Related questions: [61924](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61924/how-can-i-remove-the-window-shadow-in-mountain-lion), [126374](http://superuser.com/questions/126374/how-do-i-decrease-the-window-shadow-in-mac-os-x), [256707](http://superuser.com/questions/256707/disable-drop-shadows-around-windows-or-the-menu-bar-on-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

The program I use to do this on OS X 10.8.4 is ShadowSweeper.

http://download.cnet.com/ShadowSweeper/3000-2072_4-75966596.html

This one looks like it might also work but I haven't tried it myself.

https://github.com/puffnfresh/toggle-osx-shadows

Others have suggested the programs ShadowKiller and Nocturne. Neither worked for me.