# White part of screen flicker and drop shadow is weird, any setting need to change?

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

My MacBook Pro screen suddenly starts flickering; white does not look white and the drop shadow is inverted on white background.

[image]

Any way to disable drop shadow?

Answer (score 1):

> My MacBook Pro screen suddenly starts flickering;

Boot to [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/HT201262) by holding <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> while booting.  If the problem doesn't go away, then you have a hardware issue.

A flickering screen is hardly ever a software or setting issue especially when it starts all of a sudden.  This is indicative of a hardware issue - likely your LCD panel.

> white does not look white and the drop shadow is inverted on white background.

If colors don't look right especially white (which is all colors of the pixel being illuminated) then this is also indicative of a hardware issue - the LCD panel or your GPU.

> Any way to disable drop shadow?

This question has been asked/answered:  [Remove Window Drop Shadow and Replace with Outline](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/104462/119271)

However, this isn't the solution.  You simply cannot fix a hardware issue with a software hack.  If your display is giving problems, it's only a matter of time before it fails completely.  Your best bet is to get it checked out so you can determine if you should repair or replace your Mac.

Comment: I have not tried connecting external display, if that works fine then I can conclude that its panel issue or not GPU issue, right?

Comment: It’s a pretty good bet that if it gies away on an external monitor, it’s not your GPU,  But, there is a mux chip and related circuitry thand handles what videos signals  go where - the LCD or external display. Those have  been known to go bad